# Insert XML into a HTML Styled Timetable

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web

I'm very new to XML and using it within HTML Basically I am creating a Timetable for a school and the table is created first by defining some table headers e.g  and then defining the rows for a given student.

to make things more clearer here is some of my source code:
the first being for the tables headers

```
   <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
```

next the rows for a student

```
<tr>
        <th>David</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
            <td>TBA</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
```

my xml data file looks mainly like so:

```
 David
 Lesson:English 
Start:9
 End:10
 /David
```

Generally I just wondered what is the best possible way to implement the XML into the time table ? specifically as I'm very new to using XML so any info/source code for this problem would be greatly appreciated. specifically a student should be able to see when their lesson starts and ends. I have looked at several examples though seem to hit a brick wall so to speak when trying to implement into my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML data file in the example you have might not be valid XML - but I checked (parsed)
to make sure the XML below would be valid.

### **NOTE:**

To only select the lesson with a specific start time, see the XSLT at the end of this document.

You can use an XSLT stylesheet to transform your XML into HTML.  Here is an example
with some of the fields you used.

If you have this XML (example):  NOTE: This is only an example that is part of an existing table.
The output HTML needs to be in a  `table` block.

SAMPLE INPUT XML DOCUMENT:

```
<lessons>
  <lesson>
    <name>David</name>
    <description>English</description>
    <start>9</start>
    <end>10</end>
  </lesson>
  <lesson>
    <name>John</name>
    <description>Spanish</description>
    <start>13</start>
    <end>15</end>
  </lesson>
</lessons>
```

This XSLT stylesheet can be used to generate an HTML fragment.  You can extend this to a complete HTML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>START</th>
      <th>END</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/lessons/lesson">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="start"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="end"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT stylesheet will output this HTML fragment when the XML document is passed into a transformation; I used ORACLE PL/SQL to do a test transformation using the above XML and XSLT; the output HTML fragment only includes rows for the name, start and end nodes.

```
<tr>
  <th>NAME</th>
  <th>START</th>
  <th>END</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <tr>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

This output HTML is based on the format of the input XML document (above)..

Here is an example if you only want to report the lesson with a start time of 9:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>START</th>
      <th>END</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/lessons/lesson/start[text()='9']">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../start"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../end"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi specifically however would i be able to match the times into the timetable with certain table elements ? Also for the solution which I ran in: http://www.purplegene.com/static/transform.html, no table elements appear just the specific info

Comment: I'm getting the same HTML (XML) output as above through that transformer - what are you getting?

Comment: Yes, you can use XSLT to map the HTML output to specific row elements.  Just use the XPATH items in the XSLT to refer to the input XML document

Comment: How would I use XPATH on the code you have provided ? Sorry I'm just very new to all the XLST functions etc

Comment: As an example, to get the description node from the XML you can use (inside the existing for-each loop):

Comment: <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>

Comment: So how would I specifically get a certain element e.g a start time with 2PM ?

Comment: Hi .. I added a new XSLT at the end of this document.  It selects only the start time of 9.  NOTE that in this example, the XPATH to the start, end and name have changed because they are now relative to the start XPATH..

Comment: Awesome! thank you for the example, though this benefits how would I be able to put the information into my existing html table ?

Comment: If it's a static document, can you cut and paste the XML into the HTML using the purplegene URL?   If the XML is dynamically generated, we need to use software with an XML parser and XSLT transformation features.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's static as I created it myself so that the page gets the XML itself from the folder.